# Argument must contain a specific value - PHP

Tags: php, string, function, arguments

How can I create a PHP function that may only contain a specific value like the value may only be:

```
temperature_unit('C');
```

OR:

```
temperature_unit('F');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function temperature_unit($type) {
  if (!in_array($type, array('C', 'F'), true))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('$type must be C or F');
  // rest of your function
}
```

If you prefer, you could replace the exception with a call to [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/trigger_error).

You could also use a switch statement and throw the exception in the default case:

```
function temperature_unit($type) {
  switch ($type) {
    case 'F':
      // do work in F
      break;
    case 'C':
      // do work in C
      break;
    default:
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('$type must be C or F');
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have another question what can I do to check if `$type` is `F` or `C`?

Comment: @Me123:  If you're only checking that it equals one value, just use an equality operator:  `if ($type === 'F')`,  or see my updated answer for another example.